# How Do I Play An AnimationClip

Tags: unity, animation

I want to play an animation but it seems that in The new version of unity it is harder.  I have an AnimationClip but I don't know how to play it.  I have been looking at this for 2 hrs now and i cant get it to work.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class FPSCamera : MonoBehaviour {

public float lookSensitivity = 5;
private float xRotation;
private float yRotation;
private float currentRotationX;
private Animation walking;

void Start() {
    // DONT KNOW HOW TO FIND AND START WALKING ANIMATION
}
void Update() {
    yRotation += Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * lookSensitivity;
    xRotation -= Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * lookSensitivity;
    xRotation = Mathf.Clamp(xRotation, -90, 90);
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(xRotation, yRotation, 0);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to play an animation there needs to be an Animation Component attached to your GameObject. In that animation component you can add the animations you wish to play. If you don't want the animation to play on start make sure you un-check "Play Automatically". If you want to add more animations click the "Animations" drop down and set the "Size" to the amount of animations you wish to add.

[image]

When you want to access and play those animations you reference the Animation Component and use the "Play" method like so:

```
private Animation myAnimationComponent;

private void Start ()
{
    myAnimationComponent = GetComponent<Animation> ();
    myAnimationComponent.Play ("nameOfDesiredAnimation");
}
```

Unless you only have a few animations that you want to play at specified times, an Animator Controller would be a better option in most cases. In your case it looks like you want to animate a character; I would highly suggest using an Animator Controller instead of the Animation Component.

Let me know if you have any questions or suggestions.

Comment: Will that work on the new version of unity because the automatically play animation flag isn't there

Comment: It should. What version of Unity are you using?

Comment: i got it working

Comment: How can we programmatically import models with animation controller